# Bash script jumps to else statement and not then, shows no errors

Tags: bash, terminal

I've created a script that should read a file, then find out wether the first line has a vowel in the first word/line, and if it does, it should output only the first 10 words in the list.
If not the first 15. My issue is that the script instead of showing the first 10 lines when I input a file that starts with a vowel, it shows me the first 15 wether it's starts with a vowel or not.

My script is as following:

first reads file, then puts the first word in a variable to then be checked if it starts with a vowel, then outputs into another file.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat file.txt | word=$(head -1 file.txt)

if [[ "$word" == '^[AaEeIiOoUu]' ]]
then head -10 file.txt > words.txt
else head -15 file.txt > words.txt 
fi
```

The then statement is not acknowledged by my script, unsure why.

f.ex input file: file.txt
island
bus
carriage
train
tractor

I have tried changing the == in the 2 line to be =~.
I have tried removing, the else head -15 to see if I get the first 10 lines. Also spellcheck, and jdoodle shows no errors

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation. That being said, the shebang is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, will include that I've tried spellcheck and jdoodle , and fixed the shebang:)

Comment: You don't check for vowels. You are testing whether $word is literally the string `^[AaEeIiOoUu]`.  Also, the code for setting the variable `word` does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem 1

By putting the assignment to a pipeline, you run it in a subshell. Variable values don't propagate form a subshell to the parent process.

**Solution**

```bash
# cat file.txt | word=$(head -1 file.txt)
word=$(head -1 file.txt)
```

Also, this reads the first *line* into the variable, not the first *word*. To remove everything after the first space, you can use Parameter Expansion:

```bash
word=${word%% *}  # Remove everything from the first space onward.
```

### Problem 2

The `==` operator expects a pattern on the right hand side, not a regex. If you use `=~`, a regex is expected, *but* quotes enforce literal meaning.

**Solution**

```bash
# if [[ "$word" == '^[AaEeIiOoUu]' ]]
if [[ $word == [AaEeIiOoUu]* ]]
# or
if [[ $word =~ ^[AaEeIiOoUu] ]]
```

Moreover, if you want to test the line contains a vowerl rather than it *starts with* a vowel, you have to prepend an additional asterisk to the pattern, or remove the caret from the regex:

```bash
if [[ $word == *[AaEeIiOoUu]* ]]
# or
if [[ $word =~ [AaEeIiOoUu] ]]
```

Comment: The task is to find a vowel **in** the first word, not to test whether the first word **start** with a vowel. I personally find the task description a bit confusing, though, not the least because `word`  contains the first line of the file, and not the first word. However, the OP writes _word/line_, and I have no idea what this really is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal fix would look like

```
#!/bin/bash

# avoid doubly useless cat
word=$(head -1 file.txt)

# fix regex operator and regex
if [[ "$word" =~ [AaEeIiOoUu] ]]
then head -10 file.txt > words.txt
else head -15 file.txt > words.txt 
fi
```

though you might want to refactor to

```
if [[ "$(head -1 file.txt)" =~ [AaEeIiOoUu] ]]; then
   lines=10
else
   lines=15
fi
head -n "$lines" file.txt >words.txt
```

or even rewrite the whole thing in Awk:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { end = ($1 ~ /[AaEeIiOoUu]/ ? 10 : 15) } 1
FNR==end { exit }' file >words.txt
```

Your question seems to imply that the first line contains a single word. If you really want to focus on only the first word on the line, the shell script needs to have a slightly more elaborate regex.